# Specflow > Is there a way to execute some logic before the Scenario but AFTER the Background?

Tags: specflow

I have a scenario with several steps and there's a Background outline that inserts some initial data into the database.

Right before the scenario block executes I want to be able to start a transaction.
The thing is, I want the transaction to start AFTER the background has executed, so that if the scenario fails and I roll back, the initial data inserted in the Background is still there, because I want to do some asserts against that data.

I have tried decorating a method (in which I begin the transaction) with [BeforeScenario] and [BeforeScenarioBlock], but those are fired at the very beginning, before the Background. So that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you make the last step of your background start the transaction which would be analogous to it being an AfterBackground hook (which does not exist)? You could make it an explicit step or wrap it within your initial data setup background code to happen behind the scenes and keep it out of the feature file.

Comment: I could make the last step of the background start the transaction, but there's no guarantee this step will have to begin a transaction in some other scenario.

"You could make it an explicit step".
Yep, something like "Given I have started a transaction" but it adds "technical" language to the Gherkin I don't like very much.

"wrap it within your initial data setup background code to happen behind the scenes and keep it out of the feature file". 
I wanted to have the initial data setup "visible" in the feature file since it made it clear the base data we're starting the scenarios with.

Comment: You could also move your background stuff into a `[BeforeFeature]` then you could start your transaction in a `[BeforeScenario]`. Not ideal but might be an option...

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that this will not be possible at the moment. You should be able to add an `[AfterStep]` binding which will be called after the steps in you background and do something after the last step in the background to work around it though.

I can't remember exactly, but you might have trouble working out which step is actually executing though in the current version, but there is some stuff in the v2 version (which has a beta available from the nuget feed [here](https://ci.appveyor.com/nuget/specflow-ci)) which gives access to a `ScenarioStepContext` which might help with that.

This seems like a reasonable feature though and I don't think a pull request for extra hooks for `[BeforeBackground]` and `[AfterBackground]` would be refused. Hint. Hint.